# How can I set the thickness of the color when drawing a border around a control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I used it like that before and it's drawing a border but very thin :

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

Then I decided to put it all in a method but not sure how to set the thickness ?

```
private void DrawControlBorder(PaintEventArgs Painteventargs, Control Control, Color Color, int Thickness)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(Painteventargs.Graphics,
            Control.ClientRectangle,
            Color,
            ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
```

Comment: Can you use [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ControlPaint_DrawBorder_System_Drawing_Graphics_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_) that allows you to specify the border widths?

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct overload. Then the code will look like this:

```cs
Color color = Color.Red;
ButtonBorderStyle style = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid;
int width = 5;
Control control = pictureBox2;
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics,
    control.ClientRectangle,
    color,
    width,
    style,
    color,
    width,
    style,
    color,
    width,
    style,
    color,
    width,
    style
);
```